# Creating 'required' fields in the 'add media' window

Tags: images

I am trying to make certain fields in the 'add media' window required.
For example when you are in a post and you click "add media" I don't want the user to actually be able to send the image to the editor window unless the user has filled in a Title.
I have tried something like this:

```
$( ".media-button-insert" ).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
});
```

but the image seems to get to the editor anyways. I want to be able to stop that process and check to make sure the `title` field is filled out before actually sending the HTML to back to the editor. Has anyone been able to accomplish this or knows of a way to do this?

Comment: The question has merit, but I am not sure it is actually a smart idea as if you will succeed you will block media insertion/selection in places which are not "editors", and as the media selection is just a general utility it seems like it will be hard to detect where was it called from.